# <input type = "file"> EMPTY

Tags: php

i have this problem regarding file upload on php. 
I always get this error msg.

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\omf2\emprecords\add8.php on line 25

this is my line 25

```
$data = $con->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']));
```

But still saves the info on my database.

What i am trying to do is save the rest of the records on my database even if not selecting a file to upload. And yes the records are saved and the Attachment field (mediumblob) is [BLOB - 0 B]

Question: How can i eliminate the error/warning message? (because everything is really fine)

```
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;URL='emphistory.php'">
    <?php
    {
    echo "<center><font color='#AAA' size='3'><br/>Record Added!</center>";
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbomf");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM valueholder");   
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    $count = '';
    $IDNUM = $row['Val'];
    $NS = addslashes($_POST ['NS']);
    $ad = addslashes($_POST ['ad']);
    $hr = addslashes($_POST ['HR']);
    $name = $con->real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    $data = $con->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']));

    include ('../dbconn.php');

    $query = "INSERT INTO tblemphist1 VALUES
    ('".$count."', '".$IDNUM."', '".$NS."', '".$ad."', '".$hr."', '".$data."', '".$name."')";

   $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
   $db->close();
```

here

```
 <form method="post" action="add8.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <td><strong>Attachment</strong></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="file" name="uploaded_file"></td>
    </tr>
 </form>
```

Comment: please, post your input form

Comment: i updated my post, have i posted the one you are looking for?

Comment: no, i mean the HTML form, expecially the `<input type="file">` fields

Comment: there, updated................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type = "file">
```

should be

```
<input name="uploaded_file" type = "file">
```

also form method should be post and use enctype='multipart/form-data

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="uploaded_file" type = "file">
</form>
```

also check

```
$name = ''; $data = '';
if ((is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']) && !($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'])) {
    $name = $con->real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    $data = $con->real_escape_string(@file_get_contents($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']));
}
    include ('../dbconn.php');

    $query = "INSERT INTO tblemphist1 VALUES ('".$count."', '".$IDNUM."', '".$NS."', '".$ad."', '".$hr."', '".$data."', '".$name."')";

   $result = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
```

Comment: try with a small image file and check `print_r($data);` may be file_get_contents is not working

Comment: http://s1362.photobucket.com/user/justchx/media/here_zps787c93ff.jpg.html   here is the process. you can see the warning message that keeps on appearing on my project

Comment: use this if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) { }

Comment: still, warning is there

Comment: then use @file_get_contents to suppress the warning

Comment: how will i exactly do this? sorry i am just a month old to php

Comment: use this $con->real_escape_string(@file_get_contents($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']));

Comment: THANK YOU> IT DID REMOVE THE WARNING.

Answer (score 0):

Use an if statement. For example:

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $data = $con->real_escape_string(
        file_get_contents($_FILES['uploaded_file'] ['tmp_name'])
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply check if the variable is not empty

```
$data = '';
if (!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'])) {
    $data = $con->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']));
}
```

Comment: will this allow me to save everything to my database even if i dont select any file?

Comment: What shows you that it can't be empty? Is it database error or the same PHP error?

Comment: it is a php error, actually it is a Warning and the records are still saved if i havent selected a file. my problem is, how can i remove the warning?

Comment: Do it exactly the way I showed in my answer. It **must** work. I can't see any other calls of `file_get_contents` in your code.

Comment: http://s1362.photobucket.com/user/justchx/media/here_zps787c93ff.jpg.html   here is the image of the step by step process i did .. and you can see the warning i am pertaining

Comment: This should work:
if (isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) { ... }

Comment: @jstn Eduardo Casas is right. Did you even implement the `if` statement in your code?

Comment: @matewka yes. I did. And Still, the warning message is still there. Have you seen the picture i posted?

Comment: In fact I think my first answer would be a better choice. :P

Comment: @jstn if you implemented the code, the _line number_ in the warning would change to **27**. This means one thing - the problem is somewhere else. Please, show us the code that you have exactly in line **25**.

Comment: All answers were correct. BUT the Warning message is still present

Comment: @Matewka , i updated my question. i posted my add8.php ,,, that's the whole code. i hope you can see the error

Comment: @jstn yes, I saw it. It can't be the whole code because in line **25** there is nothing. Please, make sure that you post the whole _add8.php_ file.

Comment: yes, that's the whole code. on that post it is line 21, i just eliminated the spaces. i eliminated 4 line spaces to be exact. the error is pointing on this line.   $data = $con->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']));

Comment: Then my solution must work. The problem is somewhere else. Make sure you edited the correct file (maybe you have a duplicate somewhere). If you're using remote server, make sure you uploaded the changed file.

Comment: Actually all solutions are working. but how can i suppress the Warning message? I am not mistaken on the file or editing. Im using my localhost and i only have one copy.

Comment: @matewka ... my problem is solved. with this $data = $con->real_escape_string(@file_get_contents($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'])); provided by Harish Singh.

Answer (score 0):

Before accessing any property of `$_FILES['uploaded_file']` you have to check the value `$_FILES['uploaded_file']['error']`. And yes, it's a good idea to check if such key exists at all - as with anything coming from the user, there is no guarantee that it exists in the request.

Answer (score 0):

if error doesn't affect your project just ignore it and add this code in top of your php.

```
<?php ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); ?>
```

it will ignore and hide the error. :)